# How do I dynamically populate a shortcode with a variable from URL?

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a page that lists all live posts on a single page, with an edit link next to each one of them. The edit link to a post looks like this:

```
site.com/edit/?pid=3329&_wpnonce=9b37f6bacd
```

where 3329 is the {post_id}. Clicking the edit link takes the user to a form with shortcode:

```
[gravityforms id="1" update="xx"]
```

Is there a way i can update "xx" with 3329? Via PHP, I tried this:

```
$post_ID = get_query_var( 'pid' );

echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="2" update="' . $post_ID . '"]' );
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea where I'm failing?

Answer (score 1):

To use **[`get_query_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)**, you must first register the query variable with the `query_vars` filter.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse251014_query_vars' );
function wpse251014_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'pid';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

**Reference: [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)**

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. Is it my shortcode that is causing the problem?

       `<?php 
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse251014_query_vars' );
    function wpse251014_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
        $query_vars[] = 'pid';
        return $query_vars;
    }

    $post_ID = get_query_var( 'pid' ); 
    echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="11" update="' . $post_ID . '" title="false" description="false"]' ); ?>`